# Visual Studio hangs On Windows 7 64 bit ultimate edition, While Trying to Open an ASP.net web app

Tags: visual-studio, windows-7-x64

I am trying to migrate an ASP.net 2.0 Project from 32 bit windows xp IIS 5.1 to 64 bit windows 7 IIS 7.5. When ever i try to open the site Visual Studio 2005/2008 starts Hanging( I have tried opening the site from File System as well as IIS). I can create new project and those projects work fine not even that I was able to sucessfully migrate a ASP.net MVC project.

I have SysInternal Suite Installed. So, I can go into details and tell u if u guys need some more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok Guys,

I figured it out.. It is not only on a 64 bit OS.It is on 32 bit OS as well.. Issue was a third party dll's older version. SAFileup.dll 5.0.14, If u have this version of dll in u r bin 
then your Visual studio either version will hang.

Regards
Mohit Thakral